# prevent viewcontroller from being pushed to splitviewcontroller twice

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to prevent users from making the same selection twice or more and just pushing and pushing the same view controller onto the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

- Create BOOL value, something like
  BOOL isSelectionActive;
- Then in -
  (void)tableView:(UITableView
  *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
  *)indexPath set the isSelectionActive=TRUE;-
- Then, in - (NSIndexPath
  *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
  *)indexPath return **nil** if isSelectionActive is TRUE, otherwise
  return the indexPath.
- Before dismissing the pushed view.
  set isSelectionActive=False. You can
  do this by passing in a reference to
  the viewController that is pushing
  the new view. And setting isSelectionActive=FALSE before dismissing the view.

or

- You can set isSelectionActive = TRUE
  in viewWillAppear, which will get
  called when you dismiss the pushed
  view.

---

Answer (score 0):

That is very little information. :) But you could

a) check if the view controller is already there

b) suppress user selecting the same selection (from the information you supplied it is impossible to tell you how you should go about that)